# How to fix python environment variable conflicts with mingw64 on Windows?

Tags: python, mingw-w64

I have mingw64 installed for C tools. Right now, I am trying to manage multiple python versions using [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). I followed their installation guide, moved the path for pyenv-win to the top in environment variables. But when I run `python` in my terminal, the MSYS64's python is being run instead of pyenv-win.

Comment: Check your `PATH` environment variable (`echo $PATH`) to see if the path containing the desired `python.exe` is listed first. Also you can run `where python.exe` in your terminal to check which one it will choose.

Comment: @BrechtSanders Running `python` in the terminal chooses `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe`.

Comment: Personally I tell my projects which `python.exe` to use by explicitly telling them, e.g. adding something like `PYTHON=mypythonpath/python.exe` to the `./configure` line or by putting `PATH=mypythonpath:$PATH ` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when trying to install pyenv-win using the repo's Powershell method. By adding these following paths mentioned in the repo for both User variables Path and System variables Path in Enviroment Variables, I have been able to run the python version from pyenv-win instead of those from mingw64.

```
C:\Users\<CurrentUserName>\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims
C:\Users\<CurrentUserName>\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin
```